# Checking success variable from routes and comparing it in Angular

Tags: angular-cli, mean-stack

I am making MEAN stack app and I am registering users. In routes.js I am returning a JSON object if user is added sucessfully.

```
router.post('/register',(req,res,next)=>{
let newUser= new User({
    name:req.body.name,
    username:req.body.username,
    email:req.body.email,
    password:req.body.password
});

User.addUser(newUser,(err,user)=>{
    if(err)
    {
        res.json({success:false,msg:'Failed to Register User'});
    }
    else
    {
        res.json({success:true,msg:'Registered Sucessfully'});
    }
})})
```

Now in angular I want to check if the success true is returned and display **Flash** message but I'm getting a weird error

> Property 'success' Doesnot Exist On Type 'object'

```
this.authService.registerUser(user).subscribe(data=>{
  console.log(data);
  if(data.success)   //<---- PROPERTY 'success' DOESNOT EXIST ON TYPE 'object'
  {
    this.flashMessage.show("You are now Registered and Can LogIN",{cssClass:'alert-sucess',timeout:3000});
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);

  }
  else
  {
    this.flashMessage.show("Something Went Wrong",{cssClass:'alert-danger',timeout:3000});
    this.router.navigate(['/register']);
  }

})
```

This is my **service** class

```
registerUser(user){
let headers= new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');
return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/register',user,{headers:headers})}
```

But even with this message I'm able to add the user to database. This is what console.log is returning

[image: logs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typescript compiler error due to static type-safety checks. You can inform the compiler that no static type checking is required by using the `any` keyword, as shown below.

```
this.authService.registerUser(user).subscribe( (data: any) => {
...
```

Brackets are needed as the compiler otherwise assumes `any` is the return data type.

The application still works as JavaScript is a dynamic language, properties are looked up during runtime and the runtime is able to successfully look up the `success` property. The TypeScript compiler strips all type annotations when compiling TypeScript to JavaScript. You can see how the typescript compiler works [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play)

Comment: Ohh Thanks I was wondering the same thing as if it was compiler or run time error. I wouldn't be able to add the users. Now just have to figure out why my flash messages are not working